# li not seen when printing

Tags: html, css

I use li tag and below css for this tag :

```
<li class="line"></li>

li.line{ 
    width:100%; 
    height:3px !important; 
    background:#000; 
    list-style:none; 
    float:right;
}
```

this is ok in screen . but this is not show in print paper

thanks for help

Comment: can you show how you print it? with function?

Comment: לבני מלכה . yes . use jquery function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to see except for the background colour, and browsers do not print background colours by default.

If you want a line, then use an appropriate element (e.g. `<hr>` or `<img>`) or appropriate CSS (`border`).